# Protein Sequence Display

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel, sequence-alignment

I am trying to display protein sequence alignments in a java application for a college research project. I had the idea to use a JTable with a JLabel in each cell to hold the amino acids in the sequence. I need to be able to change the background color, text color, and have each cell event driven. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple alternative would be to use JTextArea, representing each protein sequence as a line of text, with hyphens for gaps.

If you go forward with the JTable idea, look at:

- [javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html), which allows you to provide and update data
- [javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html), which allows you to specify how to draw data

Comment: I thought about using a text area, but the user needs to be able to delete columns, insert columns, select blocks from the alignment, and have the option to shade columns with similar amino acids. I think those were what I was looking for though, thanks